# "hg forget" so file won't be deleted on other users' working directories?

Tags: mercurial

In my workplace, we're currently storing the Eclipse project file (.project) under Mercurial. However, it gets changed by Eclipse all the time, which is annoying. I want to remove it from the repository, without removing the actual file from the working directory. I know that `hg forget` does this locally, but when others will update to the revision their file will actually be removed. Adding it to `.hgignore` doesn't help.

Is there any way to mark the removed file so that Mercurial won't remove it when others update?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.ignore` will not ignore files which are version controlled.

Comment: You say that using `forget` will remove the file on other's working directories - have you tried this? That was not my impression though I use that feature rarely.

Comment: @DaveInCaz, yes, I tried this.